# Under what conditions are C++ headers not transitive?

Tags: c++, header-files

I've just run into a condition where I #include a header, I run into compilation errors that require me #including headers that were already included in the original header.

The header has the following contents:

```
#pragma once

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>

#include "itestobj.h"

extern "C" ITestObj* WINAPI GetTestObj();
```

I then get a bunch of ATL-related compilation errors when I code against that which are resolved by including `atlbase.h` and `atlcom.h` in the C++ file in addition to the above header.

Why aren't these headers being included as would normally seem to be the case?

Comment: Perhaps you need to `#include <windows.h>` instead of those inner files?

Comment: Misplacing the precompiled headers file (stdafx.h) is one such trap.  It must be #included first.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, at least one of these headers is including the file you show in your post. Since `#pramga once` tells your compiler to include it only once, it stops and you don't get all declarations.

Comment: But wouldn't that still suggest that I should be getting `atlbase.h` and `atlcom.h` from the inclusion that doesn't get excluded by `#pragma once`?

Comment: That really depends which header you are including from a cpp file.